# Most efficient way to compare two dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
dic1 = {'memory':'4','cpu':'2','disk':{'total':'160','swap':'4','/':'26','/var':'7','/tmp':'2'}}

dic2 = {'memory':8','cpu':'2','disk':{'total':'120,'swap':'4','/':'26','/var':'7','/tmp':'2'}}
```

Please note that both dictionaries itself contains another dictionary.
What is the most efficient way to compare each items without doing dict1==dict2 ?

Since i have to see some % change in values. So the only option left is iterating thru each dictionary items. something like:

```
for key1 in dic1:
   for key2 in dic2:
      if not isinstance(dic1[key1],dict):
         #compare cpu & memory here
         if int(dic1[key1]) > int(dict2[key2])
      else:
          #compare disk(internal dictionary here)
```

Comment: What you want to do with key `"disk"` and it's value that is a dictionary?

Comment: Same, i need to see % change in values in "disk" dictionary also. Yes you can consider the 'keys' remains same in both dictionaries and "disk" dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` to zip the values and compare them in a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import chain,zip_longest

["do something" if isinstance(i,dict) and all(k<v for k,v in zip_longest(i.values(),j.values())) else "do something" for i,j in zip_longest(dic1.values(),dic2.values())]
```

Note that here based on your need you can use another function instead of `all` you may be interest to use `any` or maybe you want to to some arithmetic operation on the values.

Comment: I want to compare nested dictionary values too. Interesting to know about chain & zip_longest. Hope this is used for improving the perfomrance

Comment: @akhi Since you didn't provide the what you want to do with that values I suggest a general way. Check the edit!